# ngrok installationn hangs when using pyngrok in a docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, ngrok, pyngrok

I have an API written in FastAPI python and a React frontend that interacts with the API. I need to run an ngrok tunnel using pyngrok for my frontend inside the app container and add the generated url to allow_origins in CORSMiddleware, but when the script to generate the link is run, ngrok starts installing and at 99% the installation hangs and nothing happens. Locally, the script works perfectly, but only in the container such a problem occurs, there are no errors, just the installation does not finish.

```
Downloading ngrok: 82%
Downloading ngrok: 83%
Downloading ngrok: 84%
Downloading ngrok: 85%
Downloading ngrok: 86%
Downloading ngrok: 87%
Downloading ngrok: 88%
Downloading ngrok: 89%
Downloading ngrok: 90%
Downloading ngrok: 91%
Downloading ngrok: 92%
Downloading ngrok: 93%
Downloading ngrok: 94%
Downloading ngrok: 95%
Downloading ngrok: 96%
Downloading ngrok: 97%
Downloading ngrok: 98%
Downloading ngrok: 99%
Installing ngrok ...
```

I wait for installation 20 min and nothing happens

This my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'


services:
  re:
    image: redis
    container_name: re
    command: redis-server --requirepass redistest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always 
    container_name: db
    command: -p 5435
    expose:
      - 5435
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
  
  api:
    container_name: qrmenu
    image: dchnkoo/qr-sys
    env_file:
      - qr-sys/.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
      - "5555:5555"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - re
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.12

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    supervisor \
    && rm -rf /vat/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/conf.d

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

WORKDIR /qrsystem

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN chmod +x ./*.sh

CMD [ "./app.sh" ]
```

app.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 5

python3 -m app.SECRET_KEY.generate --set-secret

sleep 5

alembic revision --autogenerate

alembic upgrade head

/usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

supervisor.conf

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:ngrok]
command=python3 -m ngrok.ngrok
directory=/qrsystem
autostart=true
stdout_logfile=/dev/fd/1
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/fd/2
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:API]
command=gunicorn app.API.api:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind=0.0.0.0:8080
directory=/qrsystem
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn_err.log

[program:celery]
command=celery --app=app.framework.celery.object:celery worker -l INFO
directory=/qrsystem
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celery_err.log

[program:flower]
command=celery --app=app.framework.celery.object:celery flower
directory=/qrsystem
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/flower.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/flower_err.log
```

pyngrok script:

```
from pyngrok import ngrok
from app.settings import origins
import os


env = os.environ

AUTH_TOKEN = env.get("NGROK_AUTHTOKEN", None)

if AUTH_TOKEN is not None:
    PORT = env.get("NGROK_PORT", "5173")
    HOST = env.get("NGROK_HOST", "127.0.0.1")

    ngrok.set_auth_token(AUTH_TOKEN)
    
    tunnel = ngrok.connect(f"{HOST}:{PORT}", "http")
    

    url = tunnel.public_url

    print(f"""\n\n\n\n\n
    ##          ##          ## ##       ## ## ##             ## ## ##        ##       ##
    ####        ##       ##       ##    ##      ##         ##        ##      ##     ##
    ##  ##      ##     ##          ##   ##       ##      ##            ##    ##   ##
    ##    ##    ##    ##                ##      ##      ##              ##   ## ## 
    ##      ##  ##    ##      ## ##     ## ## ##        ##              ##   ##   ##
    ##        ####    ##           ##   ## ##            ##            ##    ##     ##
    ##          ##     ##     ## ##     ##   ##            ##        ##      ##       ##
    ##          ##      ## ## ##        ##     ##            ## ## ##        ##         ##
          
    URL {url} -> http://{HOST}:{PORT}
    \n\n\n\n\n
    """)

    try:
        origins.remove("*")
    except:
        pass

    origins.append(url)
    
    while True:
        ...
```

i tried setting the network_mode for the container api to “host” but that didn't fix the ngrok install problem

Comment: Can you run these four processes in four separate containers, without supervisord?  That might be easier to debug.  127.0.0.1 has a fairly specific meaning, and it may not be what you expect in Docker; when you say `ngrok.connect('127.0.0.1:5173')`, where do you expect it to connect or listen?  (I don't see port 5173 otherwise mentioned in this config at all.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I run my react app on my local machine, HOST and PORT i pass in .env file which i paste in docker-compose.yml configuration and pyngrok need to make tunnel with HOST and PORT from my .env file. In .env file use my network host

Comment: Depending on context, 127.0.0.1 could mean the host system where the React app is running, the system where the end user's browser is running, the `api` container, or something inside Ngrok's infrastructure.  Is there a more specific address you mean to use here?  (You can't change the network mode via a `.env` file, and you probably don't want host networking in any case.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I running my React app on 192.67.45.252 on my machine. When I run docker-compose ngrok use host from .env file where i indicate 192.67.45.252 and tunnel will build for 192.67.45.252 with port 5173 but problem is ngrok innstalation never finish inside docker-container when supervisord start proccess -> script python3 -m ngrok.ngrok